# Find and Replace in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

Here is the code which is troubling me. I need to find the code and replace with Fancybox code, but it is throwing an error: `win` is undefined

replace the mywin value

```
<cfsavecontent variable="x">
mywin = window.open (url,"win",'toolbar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,copyhistory=yes,scrollbars=ye‌s,width=878,height=810'); 
</cfsavecontent>
```

to this:

```
mywin = $.fancybox('href' :url,'width': '500');
```

I am trying like this

```
<cfset a  = Replace(x,"mywin = window.open (url,"win",'toolbar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,copyhistory=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=878,height=810');","$.fancybox()","one")>
```

Update Code:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="foo">
      function setmycode() {
      url = "http://myurl.com?thestep=9&sortBy=1&sortOrder=1";
      mywin = window.open (url,"win",'toolbar=yes,location=yes,directories=yes,status=yes,menubar=yes,resizable=yes,copyhistory=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=878,height=810');
    mywin.focus();
    return false;
    }
  </cfsavecontent>  
  <cfset a  = Replace(foo,"mywin = window.open (url,""win"",'toolbar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,copyhistory=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=878,height=810');","$.fancybox()","one")>
  <cfdump var="#a#">
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to pay attention to your code. Even the syntax highlighting in your very question actually points out the error to you!

If an error says something about "win" and the text "win" is highlighted by a syntax highlighter... it's a bit of a give away that that is where the error lies. So that's what you should be scrutinising.

You have a string delimited with double quotes, but the string itself has double quotes in it:

```
mywin = window.open (url,"win",'toolbar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,copyhistory=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=878,height=810');
```

So the CF parser sees the first double quote around `"win"` as the end of the string. And then what follows is just garbage (and will yield a syntax error, as you are seeing).

If your string has string-delimiters within it, you need to escape them. In CFML one does this by doubling them, eg: `""` ("[Special characters](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Special+characters)")

So your string becomes:

```
mywin = window.open (url,""win"",'toolbar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,copyhistory=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=878,height=810');
```

And when delimited, it is now parseable by CF:

```
<cfset a  = Replace(x,"mywin = window.open (url,""win"",'toolbar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,copyhistory=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=878,height=810');","$.fancybox()","one")>
```

Comment: and how do i add additional double quotes to win, this is the code from cfhttp content, i cannot do it staright way, needs to be done with coldfusion

Comment: i tried ur code it did not worked checked the editing of the question please

Comment: What do you mean "this is the code from cfhttp content"? Is the code sample in your question the *actual code* you're asking about or not? There's nothing about `<cfhttp>` in that. Pls revise your question to *accurately* describe the situation you're troubleshooting with *actual code* that demonstrates the issue. Don't rely on us to guess or assume things. Read this: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/short-self-contained-correct-compilable.html, and the docs I link to in it. This is how you need to verse your questions so they're answerable.

Comment: i just posted some excerpt from the code i am getting through the cfhttp content, the problem i am facing is this code above i showed is in external site to make it work on my site, i am trying t reduce its functionality to remove window.open to fancybox so i had tried juery, that did not worked, so i am trying cf now